# Data with a cedilla - Ç - in mysql table

Tags: mysql, collation

I was trying to determine an error in a java program that loads MySQL tables every night.

> Error in the log was **java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value:
>   '\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD...' for column 'manager' at row 1**.

Finally determined there was a new name in the data (loading from a flat file) - FRANÇOIS - and it was the cedilla that was giving the error.  Program still loaded everything, just left that field blank.

When I ran a `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FOR tablename`, it was `latin1_swedish_ci`.  I know very little about collation, charsets. 
What should I change the collation to in order for it to accept this?

Answer (score 0):

(To long for a comment)

Need to see more details.

Don't use latin1; use utf8.

Connect with `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the `getConnection()` call

Use `CHARACTER SET utf8` in the table and/or column definition.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for confirmation.

EFBFBD is the "replacement" character, implying that you had garbage coming it.

Loading a flat file -- Can you get the hex of `Ç` from the file?  If it is `C7` it is latin1 and you should specify latin1 on the load.  Is it `LOAD DATA`?  Or something else?

If it is `C387` then it is utf8; good.

More discussion, debugging, best practice, etc:  [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Terminology:  "Collation" (eg, latin1_swedish_ci) refers to sort order.  Your problem is with "Character set" (eg, latin1 or utf8).

Comment: The SHOW CREATE TABLE statement shows it used the Default Charset, which is latin1.  I will have to verify whether I am allowed access to change that table to uft8, or if there was a particular reason the default is latin1.

Comment: It is ancient history.  The latest version of MySQL defaults to utf8mb4.  Still, you can explicitly specify `CHARACTER SET ...` on each `VARCHAR`.

Comment: How do a change the char set for a specific column?  That would be best solution so it doesn't cause problems with any other programs that might be using that same table.

Comment: Trouble ensues if you are `JOINing` on that column.  But, let's back up a bit.  Please show all the charset details and connection details.  We _may_ be able to solve your problem without changing the table/col charset.

Comment: Don't know that I have access to the connection details - I did not create the java program.  It is called by a shell script.

Comment: Here are the charset details for the database -

character_set_client     | latin1                     
character_set_connection | latin1               
character_set_database   | utf8 character_set_filesystem | utf8                      
character_set_results    | latin1                    
character_set_server     | utf8                       
character_set_system     | utf8                       
character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/